# Constructing a return in R

Tags: r, return

I have a function in R that I run on lists of flies. After the following code I apply the function to files and have R put the values in a new file. An equation in this function outputs a value based on water density and depth. I found that the top row of the depth is not always 1 in these files, but I need it to be for the equation. I would like to be able to output an "NA" message into the new sheet for when it is not.

```
stratindex=function(file){      
    ctd=read.csv(file,header=T)         
    x=ctd$Density..sigma.t..kg.m.3..    
    y=ctd$Depth..salt.water..m...lat...60
    if(y[1]!=1){return(NA)} else
    ((x[30]-x[1]) / 29)             
}
```

This all reads in fine. Then I get to the next part, where it takes the individual files and applies the function to them.

```
the.files <- choose.files()                         
index <- sapply(the.files, stratindex)
```

After this, R prompts:

> "Error in if (y[1] != 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Where did I go wrong? What can I do to nest other stipulations if I find them? For instance, if the depth at row 30 is not 30.

Comment: You can check if `y` is incorrect by printing `length(y)` or by putting a condition `if(length(y) > 0)` on the `if( y[1] != 1)` block.

Comment: How do I make it recognize that y is incorrect, put in "NA" where that value belongs, and just move on to the next file?